# Divergence and rotation of ideal dipole field at d --> 0

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, dipole, dipole-moment

I am working on an assignment in vector calculus where we are supposed to find the divergence and the rotation of the electric field caused by an ideal dipole when the distance d between the charges goes towards zero. We do get graded on first principle reasoning and compactness of solutions.

My understanding is that there is nothing special about the dipole, it is basically two equal charges of opposite polarity separated by the distance d. That means that we should be able to find a scalar potential by simply using the principle of superposition.

Due to the fact that the scalar potential exist, the rotation of the field has to be zero, which leaves out the necessity of any calculations.

When it comes to the divergence, I have an expression of the potential for points outside the dipole in spherical coordinates, which I derived using the far field limit. 
I can find the divergence in the two following ways:

- Taking the divergence of the gradient of the scalar potential, which would be equal to using the Laplacian in spherical coordinates.
- Using Gauss Law from Classical Field Theory, which says that the divergence of any electric field through a closed surface is a sum of the enclosed charges divided by $\epsilon_0$.

**My question is this:**
When the distance d approaches zero, I feel like it would be impossible to find a closed surface that does not enclose both the positive and the negative charge, which would directly lead to the conclusion the the divergence has to be zero?
Are my assumptions that lead to the divergence and rotation being zero correct, or am I missing something fundamental? I almost feel like this is "to simple".

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the divergence of a dipole field is indeed zero.

Comment: @Felix Darke, why don't you use Maxwell's equations? They solve the problem instantaneously.